# Switching from TTY to GUI logs user out

Tags: 14.04, gui, tty

When I try switching back to GUI from TTY, I have to login again, and most of the stuff I had running on GUI before is now gone. Is this usual behavior? How do I get it to keep my work?

Possibly related, at random times (possibly when using some commands, always when I use `kill`), it restarts the GUI, and I have to switch back to the TTY after loging in the GUI again.

Comment: That is very unusual. What do you `kill`?

Comment: Just a nonessential program running on a wine server

Comment: And how do you kill it?

Comment: using `kill <PID>`